# Homebrew installation of OpenCV 3.0 not linking to Python

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew, opencv3.0

When I install OpenCV 3.0 with Homebrew, it gives me the following directions to link it to Python 2.7:

> If you need Python to find bindings for this keg-only formula, run:
>   echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages >>
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth

While I can find the python2.7 site packages in opencv3, no python34 site packages were generated. Does anyone know how I can link my OpenCV 3.0 install to Python 3?

Comment: Here is an installation guide which helps you to install OpenCV 3 in Python 3.4 on OSX: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/

Comment: Cheers, I was following this before, I just don't understand why Homebrew doesn't support Python 3 with OpenCV 3 when that was one of the big benefits of the new version.

Answer (score 7):

It's weird that there is no concise instruction for installing OpenCV 3 with Python3. So, here I make it clear step-by-step:

1. Install Homebrew Python 3.5: `brew install python3`
2. Tap homebrew/science: `brew tap homebrew/science`
3. Install **any** Python3 packages using `pip3`. This will create the `site-packages` folder for Python3 
   For example:
   `pip3 install numpy`
4. Then install OpenCV3 `brew install opencv3 --with-python3`
5. Now you can find the `site-packages` folder created in Step 2. Just run the following command to link Opencv3 to Python3:
   `echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv3.pth`

You may have to change the above command correpondingly to your installed Homebrew Python version (e.g. 3.4).

Comment: For me the step that I was missing was the `brew tap homebrew/science` thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install opencv like `brew install opencv3 --with-python3`. You can see a list of options for a package by running `brew info opencv3`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the advice, I tried using that flag and it gives me this message while I install and doesn't install cv2 for Python3:
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x!
     PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages"
     You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.

I tried the unset command and reinstallation but it doesn't work, I don't understand where this is coming from because both python 2 and python 3 were installed by Homebrew on my machine - I even wiped the hard drive and reinstalled Yosemite.